# KnockoutJs - Sort objects by numeric property

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, client, knockout-3.0

There are multiple knockoutJS resources which show how to sort objects over string values(ex. FirstName, LastName) but couldn't find way to sort using numeric values (ex. Marks, Salary, Age)

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imsangram/0kLg4w38/1/) has necessary data and I would like to sort objects in ascending as well as descending direction depending on field '*mark*'

I tried using `parseInt`but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to invoke "mark" as observable here is a working version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/kuedwryz/1/

```
//use 
right.mark()

//instead of 
right.mark
```

Comment: ohh !  Just realized that I don't even need ParseInt. Thanks dude!